# d3: Hierarchical Edge Bundling with mouse click on links

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, mouseclick-event, hierarchical

I am trying to replicate the [Hierarchical edge bundling case](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999) but adding mouseover and click to the links created (path in svg). When I add `.on("click")` or `.on("mouseover")` to `link` besides being on the event listener they don't work.

The change I have made to the example was:

```
  link = link
  .data(bundle(links))
  .enter().append("path")
  .each(function(d) {
    d.source = d[0], d.target = d[d.length - 1];
  })
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", line)
  .on('click', function(d) {
    alert('mouseover');
  });
```

My code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/migtorres/7yt7r6oz/).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `pointer-events: none;` CSS rule that match the SVG paths. With this rule, your paths never receives the mouse events.

Simply remove this rule to be able to catch clicks and mouseover events.

But generally this rule is present for a reason, so removing it might have undesirable side effect, even if after a quick test everything seemed to work as expected.

Comment: Yes, I confirm, I removed it and now it works perfectly. Thanks.